# Authentication methods for SharePoint REST API

Tags: rest, authentication, api, authorization, sso

Let's say I work in company AAA and want to automatically upload documents to BBB's company SharePoint Online application https://BBB.sharepoint.com using REST API.

My email username@AAA.com is invited to https://BBB.sharepoint.com and I can Sign-in via SSO.

Which authentification methods I can use for generating access token?

Is there a way apart registering SharePoint Add-In as it may be a difficult thing to do (I don't have access to BBB SharePoint configurations)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to achieve this access - we need to generate a **client_id** and **client_secret** from "https://BBB.sharepoint.com" site and uses that code in "AAA" site while sending the data "BBB" site.

There is a long steps how to the generate the **client_id** and **client_secret** code.

**Step 1: Register Add-In**

Go to the this page of your BBB site https://.SharePoint.com/_layouts/15/appregnew.aspx

Here you will get: **client id** and **client secret**

Save this information in notepad.

**Step 2: Grant Permissions to Add-In**

Go to this page of your BBB site:

https://.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/appinv.aspx

Enter the "Client ID" in the App ID field and click on Lookup button

Now enter the below permission request in XML format:

```
<AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">
    <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection/web" Right="Read" />
</AppPermissionRequests>
```

**Step 3: Retrieve the Tenant ID**

In POST man tool do a GET request for this URL(BBB site):

https:///sharepoint.com/_vti_bin/client.svc/

From the Header section you will get the **realm** value which is nothing but your client ID.

So finally while you are sending the **client id** and **client secret** to the **AAA** site(your source site from where you are uploading the document), it should be in the below format:

```
client_id   ClientID@TenantID
client_secret   ClientSecret
```

**Example:**

```
client_id: 4b4276d0-74cd-4476-b66f-e7e326e2cb93@10267809-adcb-42b6-b103-c7c8190b3fed
client_secret: nuC+ygmhpadH93TqJdte++C37SUchZVK4a5xT9XtVBU=
```

Now when the other system here it is application **"AAA site"** performing the **POST** call to the "SharePoint site here it is https://BBB.sharepoint.com", they need to use these two **client_id** and **client_secret** key.

**Detailed explanation is here:**

https://www.ktskumar.com/2017/01/access-sharepoint-online-using-postman/

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  Does this mean that there is no other way for authorisation apart registering Add-in?

Comment: I think there is other way also either thru direct dedicated username and password via azure, and thru the Azure Application ID - that need be configured in Azure - but the Client_ID and Client_Secret is the standard one.